# Complex tire query involving nested models

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have the following models.

```
class Author
    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks

    has_many :books
    has_many :tags #(eg: 'german', 'philosopher')
end

class Book
    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :book_type #(eg: 'paperback', 'hardcover')
    has_many :tags #(eg: 'crime', 'drama')
end
```

I need help in understanding and writing the following search queries,

```
Find all authors who are tagged as 'german' AND 'philosopher'
                     have written at least 1 book each of book_type 'paperback' AND 'hardcover'
                     where each such book is tagged as 'crime' AND 'drama'

Find all authors who are tagged as 'german' AND 'philosopher'
                     have written at least 1 book of any book_type
                     where that book is tagged as 'crime' AND 'drama'
```

I added a mini rails project with sample seed data @ https://github.com/rahul/nested_tire_query_problem

**UPDATE**

I tried to write a mapping for author in include books as type 'nested'. But the to_indexed_json method overrides the definition in the mapping and creates non-nested books inside author.

Backend: MySQL (I use to_indexed_json to feed documents to elasticsearch)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry the community couldn't help, I think the tire tag scared them off! A lot of the elasticsearch crowd don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Here is the link to the answer: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/794